# Index Out of Range in Python

Tags: python

Below is the code

```
infile = ['02000YBSD', 'GBP', '20140930', '1.66928', '1', '1']
for line in infile:
    a = line.split()
    fdmAPI.logInfo(str(a))
    CheckNumeric = a[4]
    fdmAPI.logInfo(CheckNumeric[1])
```

Comment: CheckNumeric returns something which doesn't have 2 elements, I suppose

Comment: `split()` by default splits on space. Why do you think that "GBP" has an `a[4]` element ?

Comment: Actually the file is separted with spaces and i am using split  and then getting the 4 element whic is 1. However it gives me the out of range error

Answer (score 0):

You tried to access to the 4 element of an array with a length lower than 4:

```
>>> line = '1'
>>> a = line.split()
>>> print a, len(a)
['1'] 1
>>> CheckNumeric = a[4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```